# I've turned display_errors to On but I don't see any errors on the webpages

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to see what error PHP is producing. So I've changed the value of **dispaly_errors** to ON in the `etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file.

The file doesn't display anything and I don't see any error on the webpages.

Am I missing any thing?

Comment: It's display, not dispaly? Typo, or is it wrong at server side as well? Furthermore I guess you mean `/etc/php5/...` and not `etc/php5/...` there is a big difference....

Comment: you should also set the level of error reporting

Comment: It may sounds dumb but you restarted the server after changing the value?

Comment: @ForguesR: restarting the server has solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to make sure that this is your correct ini file. Usually the file you have used is the correct one. If not sure, you can create a simple PHP program to call the phpinfo() function and check this out.

Next, you have to restart Apache. Without a restart your settings don't take effect.

Another thing... This file can be a little misleading because there are so many comments in it. The actual line to change is way down. On my setup (LAMP/Ubuntu) the setting is on line 538.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to enabling display_errors, you may also need to set the [error reporting level](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting). if you are expecting errors with a script that is redirecting, be sure to turn off the redirection or you may never see them.

Comment: If there's an error, in the syntax or something related to a missing function, program execution stops. Thus redirection does not happen. So turning off redirection shouldn't be done.

Comment: That's based on the level of the error, it isn't always halted. Anyway, I changed "won't" to "may not".

Answer (score 1):

Open php.ini file from your php folder, remove semicolon from all error reporting like
    `;error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`,  `;display_errors=On` etc, at last, restart your server, you will find all error messages.

Another way for showing error, you can write these codes in your script -

```
echo '<pre>';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```